# EF Union issue "cannot convert from <AnonymusType#1 to AnonymusType#2>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This should be a simple union query but even if action types are same it is throwing me an error:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>`

If I remove this column then it is working fine. In first select I want to assign action value to '0'. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
(from p in Pages join pa in PageAct on p.PageId equals pa.PageId
 select new
 {
     PageId = p.PageId,
     PgName = p.PgName,
     ActionId = pa.ActionId,
     ActionName = pa.ActionName,
     **action = 0**
 }).Union(from p in Pages
 join pa in PageAct on p.PageId equals pa.PageId
 join rp in RolePerm on pa.ActionId equals rp.ActionId into jrs
 from jrResult in jrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where jrResult.RoleId == 1
 select new
 {
     PageId = p.PageId,
     PgName = p.PgName,
     ActionId = pa.ActionId,
     ActionName = pa.ActionName,
     action = jrResult.ActionId
 })
```

Comment: Please show where you actually use the query an execute it

Comment: jrResult.ActionId can be null, so the only way to do this is to cast to a nullable int in the first anonymous object `action = (int?)0` and if jrResult.ActionId is a non-nullable type, then I suggest to do the same there `action = (int?)jrResult.ActionId`

Comment: I am using LinqPad

Comment: @Silvermind thanks it worked

Comment: @Silvermind - Its worth adding this as an anwer

Comment: Yes agreed. Can you post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous objects should have exactly the same signature to be considered identical.

If `RolePerm.ActionId` is a nullable type, the first anonymous object property type should also be nullable.
The actual type can also be non-nullable, but since this is a left join you should not forget to cast to a nullable int explicitly, otherwise you might get runtime exceptions.

```
(from p in Pages join pa in PageAct on p.PageId equals pa.PageId
 select new
 {
     PageId = p.PageId,
     PgName = p.PgName,
     ActionId = pa.ActionId,
     ActionName = pa.ActionName,
     action = (int?)0
 }).Union(from p in Pages
 join pa in PageAct on p.PageId equals pa.PageId
 join rp in RolePerm on pa.ActionId equals rp.ActionId into jrs
 from jrResult in jrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where jrResult.RoleId == 1
 select new
 {
     PageId = p.PageId,
     PgName = p.PgName,
     ActionId = pa.ActionId,
     ActionName = pa.ActionName,
     action = (int?)jrResult.ActionId // should cast, even if ActionId is not nullable
                                      // because left join might give null
 })
```